# URL and GUID values from Feed import

Tags: 7, feeds

When you import RSS items via [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds), where are the URL and GUID target values stored in the node?  How do you get these out?  I am not seeing anything close to these when I dump the `$node`.

This shows the **Mappings** screen with the values that I am talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are stored in the feeds_item table in the database. They are used by the feeds module to control updates of imported items.

Comment: If you need the link in a template, is the only way to get it is by adding an additional mapping onto a field in the content type, or is this somewhere in the $node already?

Comment: I don't think they're in the $node and I would use extra mappings. If your familiar with the devel module (more importantly if your not!) you can download and enable [devel] (http://drupal.org/project/devel) and use the kpr function to view the node object. Devel is a great tool for developers.

Comment: Thanks.  The question started because I wasn't seeing the info when I did a kpr($node), and was rather surprised that it wasn't there.  There are 100 ways to tackle this, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel or duplicate the data if it was somewhere that I wasn't seeing.

Comment: No, I think duplicate mappings if you need them. Beware, feeds also checks a hash of the import to check for updates (see FeedsProcessor.inc) I'm not sure what your using this for, but if your looking at what version gets updated when you'll need hash data from that table as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`feeds_item_info_load()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!feeds!feeds.module/function/feeds_item_info_load/7) to get the feed item object, eg:

```
$fii = feeds_item_info_load('node', $node->nid);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem .. I use a db_query to retrieve the source

if you need to load information from feed_items then use feeds_item_info_load. However I need to load the source URL, and so far I havent found anything to do that. With the dbase query below you can retrieve the source feed.

```
$key = 'www.somefeed.com';
$result = db_query('SELECT feed_nid from feeds_source where source = :source', array(':source'=>$key ));

foreach ($result as $record) {
    $feed_nid[] = $record;
    }
```